# Windows Phone 8.1 Connect to Pebble via Bluetooth Rfcomm

Tags: c#, bluetooth, windows-phone-8.1, pebble-watch

I have a problem when I trying to connect with pebble watch via bluetooth.
This is my code:

```
var serviceId = Guid.Parse("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB").ToString("B");
PeerFinder.Start();
PeerFinder.AlternateIdentities["Bluetooth:Paired"] = "";
var pairedDevices = await PeerFinder.FindAllPeersAsync();
PeerInformation selectedPeer = pairedDevices[0];
var streamSocket = new StreamSocket();
await streamSocket.ConnectAsync(selectedPeer.HostName, serviceId);
```

Also in manifest:

```
<Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
    <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="proximity" />
    <m2:DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.rfcomm">
        <m2:Device Id="any">
            <m2:Function Type="serviceId:00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"/>
        </m2:Device>
    </m2:DeviceCapability>
</Capabilities>
```

So the exception throws in `await streamSocket.ConnectAsync(selectedPeer.HostName, serviceId);`.

Exception: `Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)`

I have already seen same questions but I didn't find a solution of the problem.

- Windows Phone 8.1
  Lumia 929
- Pebble AF57
  Firmware v2.9

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, just replace service id by `00000000-deca-fade-deca-deafdecacaff`